ConnectError: All connection attempts failed when connecting indexing to neo4j database using PropertyGraphIndex from llama3
I am working on knowledge graph and all connection to neo4j browser is a success(using neo4j desktop windows not docker deployed). however with llama3 i am running the same notebooks as in property graph construction with predefined schemas documentation.
all cells run with success except when the following code runs
from llama_index.core import PropertyGraphIndex
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedding

index = PropertyGraphIndex.from_documents(
    documents,
    kg_extractors=[kg_extractor],
    embed_model=HuggingFaceEmbedding(model_name="BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5"),
    property_graph_store=graph_store,
    vector_store=vec_store,
    show_progress=True,
)

It throws an error: ConnectError: All connection attempts failed
What i have done:
I have installed the APOC pluging, all apoc procedures looks good
All connections looks good
However, i still can't figure out why i keep getting An error occurred while creating the PropertyGraphIndex: All connection attempts failed i try to parse the nodes and extract paths from text with schema.
Any Help on this will be greatly appreciated. I will also provide entire script below.
%pip install llama-index
%pip install llama-index-llms-ollama
%pip install llama-index-embeddings-huggingface
# Optional
%pip install llama-index-graph-stores-neo4j
%pip install llama-index-graph-stores-nebula

#Load data
!mkdir -p 'data/paul_graham/'
!wget 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/run-llama/llama_index/main/docs/docs/examples/data/paul_graham/paul_graham_essay.txt' -O 'data/paul_graham/paul_graham_essay.txt'

from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("./data/paul_graham/").load_data()

# Graph Construction
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

from typing import Literal
from llama_index.llms.ollama import Ollama
from llama_index.core.indices.property_graph import SchemaLLMPathExtractor

# best practice to use upper-case
entities = Literal["PERSON", "PLACE", "ORGANIZATION"]
relations = Literal["HAS", "PART_OF", "WORKED_ON", "WORKED_WITH", "WORKED_AT"]

# define which entities can have which relations
validation_schema = {
    "PERSON": ["HAS", "PART_OF", "WORKED_ON", "WORKED_WITH", "WORKED_AT"],
    "PLACE": ["HAS", "PART_OF", "WORKED_AT"],
    "ORGANIZATION": ["HAS", "PART_OF", "WORKED_WITH"],
}
validation_schema = [
    ("ORGANIZATION", "HAS", "PERSON"),
    ("PERSON", "WORKED_AT", "ORGANIZATION"),
    ("PERSON", "WORKED_WITH", "PERSON"),
    ("PERSON", "WORKED_ON", "ORGANIZATION"),
    ("PERSON", "PART_OF", "ORGANIZATION"),
    ("ORGANIZATION", "PART_OF", "ORGANIZATION"),
    ("PERSON", "WORKED_AT", "PLACE"),
]

kg_extractor = SchemaLLMPathExtractor(
    llm=Ollama(model="llama3", json_mode=True, request_timeout=3600),
    possible_entities=entities,
    possible_relations=relations,
    kg_validation_schema=validation_schema,
    # if false, allows for values outside of the schema
    # useful for using the schema as a suggestion
    strict=True,
)

# Neo4j
from llama_index.graph_stores.neo4j import Neo4jPropertyGraphStore

graph_store = Neo4jPropertyGraphStore(
    username="neo4j",
    password="",
    url="bolt://localhost:7687",
)
vec_store = None

# start building
from llama_index.core import PropertyGraphIndex
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedding

index = PropertyGraphIndex.from_documents(
    documents,
    kg_extractors=[kg_extractor],
    embed_model=HuggingFaceEmbedding(model_name="BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5"),
    property_graph_store=graph_store,
    vector_store=vec_store,
    show_progress=True,
)


can you give us the entire script that you are running? how did you define graph_store?

@jose_bacoy the entire script i am running from the llama index documentation i provided. They have define graph_store has the following parameters
`from llama_index.graph_stores.neo4j import Neo4jPropertyGraphStore
graph_store = Neo4jPropertyGraphStore(
username="neo4j",
password="",
url="bolt://localhost:7687",
)
vec_store = None`
